# File I/O error Copy Constructor C++

Tags: c++, file, io, fstream

I am trying to make a program with some simple methods, and this is one of my classes:

Example.cpp:

```
#include "Example.hpp"

using namespace std;

ifstream Example::getStream(const char *inputFile) const {
    ifstream myFile;
    myFile.open(inputFile);
    return myFile;
}
```

Example.hpp:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <map>

#ifndef EXAMPLE_HPP
#define EXAMPLE_HPP

using namespace std;

class Example {
    public:
        map<int, int> *exampleMap;

    ifstream getStream(const char *inputFile) const;
};

#endif
```

This is implemented by other subclasses in the program, and it will be very useful in the future. However, for now, when I try to build this, it returns me these errors:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ios:42:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/istream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/fstream:38,
                 from ../Example.hpp:1,
                 from ../Example.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/ios_base.h: In copy constructor ‘std::basic_ios<char>::basic_ios(const std::basic_ios<char>&)’:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/ios_base.h:786:5: error: ‘std::ios_base::ios_base(const std::ios_base&)’ is private
     ios_base(const ios_base&);
     ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ios:44:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/istream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/fstream:38,
                 from ../Example.hpp:1,
                 from ../Example.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_ios.h:66:11: error: within this context
     class basic_ios : public ios_base
           ^
In file included from ../Example.hpp:1:0,
                 from ../Example.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/fstream: In copy constructor ‘std::basic_ifstream<char>::basic_ifstream(const std::basic_ifstream<char>&)’:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/fstream:427:11: note: synthesized method ‘std::basic_ios<char>::basic_ios(const std::basic_ios<char>&)’ first required here 
     class basic_ifstream : public basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>
           ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ios:43:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/istream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/fstream:38,
                 from ../Example.hpp:1,
                 from ../Example.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/streambuf: In copy constructor ‘std::basic_filebuf<char>::basic_filebuf(const std::basic_filebuf<char>&)’:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/streambuf:802:7: error: ‘std::basic_streambuf<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_streambuf(const std::basic_streambuf<_CharT, _Traits>&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]’ is private
       basic_streambuf(const basic_streambuf& __sb)
       ^
In file included from ../Example.hpp:1:0,
                 from ../Example.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/fstream:72:11: error: within this context
     class basic_filebuf : public basic_streambuf<_CharT, _Traits>
           ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/fstream: In copy constructor ‘std::basic_ifstream<char>::basic_ifstream(const std::basic_ifstream<char>&)’:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/fstream:427:11: note: synthesized method ‘std::basic_filebuf<char>::basic_filebuf(const std::basic_filebuf<char>&)’ first required here 
     class basic_ifstream : public basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>
           ^
../Example.cpp: In member function ‘std::ifstream Example::getStream(const char*) const’:
../Example.cpp:13:12: note: synthesized method ‘std::basic_ifstream<char>::basic_ifstream(const std::basic_ifstream<char>&)’ first required here 
     return myFile;
            ^
make: *** [Example.o] Error 1
```

I am trying to figure out what I have done wrong here. Is it something with the includes? Is it some typo I can't see.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to return the stream **by value**. This is not possible pre-C++11 (and with gcc 4.X's standard library implementation) as streams cannot be copied and C++98 does not have move semantics.

So in C++11, this code is fine; if your implementation does not yet fully implement it, you need a workaround like passing in a non-`const` reference, eg:

```
#ifndef EXAMPLE_HPP
#define EXAMPLE_HPP

#include <fstream>
#include <map>

class Example
{
public:
    std::map<int, int> *exampleMap;

    bool openFile(const char *inputFile, std::ifstream &myFile) const;
};

#endif
```

```
#include "Example.hpp"

bool Example::openFile(const char *inputFile, std::ifstream &s) const
{
    myFile.open(inputFile);
    return myFile.is_open();
}
```

```
#include "Example.hpp"

Example ex;
std::ifstream myFile;

if (ex.openFile("filename", myFile))
{
   //...
}
```